# lock git branch from cli in azure

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I need to create a new branch from cli, push it to origin and then lock it.

My project is managed in Azure. 
Now my script looks like this:

```
git checkout -b new_branch  %GIT_COMMIT%
git push origin new_branch
git checkout master
```

That works perfectly. 
Now I am looking for a way to lock the branch in azure.
According to their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/lock-branches?view=azure-devops) I can do it in the console, or lock the [repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/repos/ref?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-repos-ref-lock) from cli.

But I am looking for a way to lock the branch from cli. 
Is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the REST API or [az-cli /w the devops extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/repos/ref?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-repos-ref-lock):

```
 az repos ref lock --name heads/master
```

In general:

```
 az repos ref lock --name {ref to the branch you want to lock}
```

This will prevent pushes to the branch in general. You may want to use a Branch Policy instead to enforce a PR is created to merge with the branch.

```
 az repos policy merge-strategy create --blocking {false, true}
                                  --branch master
                                  --enabled true
                                  --repository-id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use web hooks to do it.
Add a `pre-commit` hook and return exit code 1.

---

#### ***[`pre-commit hook`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)***

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Redirect output to screen.
exec 1>&2

# Output colors
red='\033[0;31m';
green='\033[0;32m';
yellow='\033[0;33m';
default='\033[0;m';

# personal touch :-)
echo "${red}"
echo "                                         "
echo "                   |ZZzzz                "
echo "                   |                     "
echo "                   |                     "
echo "      |ZZzzz      /^\            |ZZzzz  "
echo "      |          |~~~|           |       "
echo "      |        |-     -|        / \      "
echo "     /^\       |[]+    |       |^^^|     "
echo "  |^^^^^^^|    |    +[]|       |   |     "
echo "  |    +[]|/\/\/\/\^/\/\/\/\/|^^^^^^^|   "
echo "  |+[]+   |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|    +[]|   "
echo "  |       |  []   /^\   []   |+[]+   |   "
echo "  |   +[]+|  []  || ||  []   |   +[]+|   "
echo "  |[]+    |      || ||       |[]+    |   "
echo "  |_______|------------------|_______|   "
echo "                                         "
echo "                                         "
echo "{green}You cannot commit to this branch  " 
echo "                                         "
echo "${default}"

# set the exit code to 0 or 1 based upon your needs
# 0 = good to continue
# 1 = exit without committing.
exit 1;
```

---

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking to lock it in azure.